# Access DataContext in code-behind

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datacontext

Beware, this is a rather basic question (I think).

I have a UserControl, called MyUserControl. I use it in a DataTemplate for my ListBox:

```
<l:MyUserControl DataContext="Test" />
```

Now I want to access this DataContext in the code-behind of MyUserControl, and I expect DataContext to contain a string object with contents "Test". However, DataContext is null. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to access the DataContext property in code behind, give the user control (or any controls for that matter) a name:

in code behind:

myControl.DataContext = someobject;

Although in your example setting the DataContext to "Test" will accomplish nothing.

Read up on data binding in WPF
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa480224.aspx

Comment: Shouldn't it be the other way? Something like:

var theDataContext = (SomeViewModelType) myControl.DataContext;

Or at least:

var theDataContext = myControl.DataContext;

op doesn't want to set the data context but to access it.

Answer (score 1):

You need some field or propertie in MyUserControl's class named DataContext.

See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wt9d35z6(VS.71).aspx) to learn about user control properties in .net.

Comment: UserControl already has a property called DataContext, so my inherited class will also have this property..